# "gem install autotest-fsevent" -v 0.1.1 fails on snow leopard

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fsevents

Following Michael Hartl's Rails 2.3 tutorial.  Excellent, so far, but I am stuck on the prep for the testing environment on page 87.  Can't get the autotest-fsevent to install.

iMac i7 running Snow Leopard.

Typing the command in the Title, above, I get the following error message:

bash-3.2$ sudo gem install autotest-fsevent -v 0.1.1
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing autotest-fsevent:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

```
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/bin/ruby extconf.rb
```

mkmf.rb **can't find header files for ruby at /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/1.8/usr/lib/ruby/ruby.h**

Gem files will remain installed in /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sys-uname-0.8.6 for inspection.
Results logged to /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/sys-uname-0.8.6/ext/gem_make.out

I've tried downloading a ruby 1.8.7 fresh install to get the header files, but that has not seemed to work.  Copied them to the path in bold, above.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

-lloyd

Comment: Do you have [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/xcode/) installed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Do you have Xcode installed?"

Thanks for checking.  In fact, I didn't realize that there was a difference between Xcode in the standard Snow Leopard install and the one downloaded from the Apple Developer Network.  I have installed the full Xcode and the problem is now solved.

Cheers,

lloyd